# JSON image set to FALSE

Tags: php

I'm using the php code below to display an image using it's URL which is written in a JSON file

```
<img src="<?php echo $post->featured_image->sizes->full->url ?>">
```

This works fine with many of the images but in the JSON file the 'featured_image' property on the missing images is set to false as:

```
"featured_image":false,"media":[{"id":8188,:... etc
```

When the page loads, the missing images are displaying the 'Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp... ' error and I found through using the chrome inspecter they are giving a forbidden 403 message

I am quite new to JSON and was wondering firstly why these images are set to FALSE and if there is a way round it to display all teh images

Comment: You need to have conditional test in your code that first looks to make sure the featured_image property of your post is defined as you'd expect it... If it is, display your image, if it is not, do something else. The error you're getting is due to you trying to get the sizes properties of a boolean (when it's false).

Comment: If you cannot guarantee that a member exists you have to check each value before accessing `->`.

Comment: Thanks, I did the below test and it did echo false on the missing images and true on the ones showing. But I can seem to incorporate it into my code

Comment: <?php
     if ($post->featured_image == false) { 
     echo "false"; 
     } 

     else
     {
      echo "true"; 
     }

Comment: @wilky You might be getting it from a 3rd Party API. Isn't it? If so then you must have to check if featured_image param is false or true. If its false then just add a check.
<?php if ($post->featured_image === false) { echo 'false'; } else { echo 'true'; }

Comment: Thanks for your reply.